# Rails Active Record Relation sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

Let's say I have a ruby on rails model, with a text field. Let's say I also have a query string. I want to make a query that sorts the database in descending order of maximal number of overlapping characters between the text field and the query string. How would I go about this?

Comment: can you write some example of what you want?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can go with `LIKE` SQL statement, but will not be efficient.
Here is an example:

```
Company.where(Company.arel_table[:name].matches("%stack%"))
```

If you need to make a lot of queries search the text inside a field in database, you really need to start looking for a full text search software.

I can recommend you [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/elasticsearch), unless you are familiar with some other tool.

You have [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/) a recent tutorial and also a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/306-elasticsearch-part-1) on subject.